# Unwanted characters in django URLs

Tags: python, django

The problem is i have a url pattern in my urls.py that has a problem generating links in persian lanauge:

app urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^/(?P<posts_category>\w+)/$',
          views.category_archives, name="posts_archive")
]
```

template:

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for category in categories %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'post:posts_archive' category.category %}">
                   {{ category.category }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

app views.py:

```
def category_archives(request, posts_category):
    category_archive = Post.objects.filter(category = posts_category)
    template = 'template.html'
    context = {"posts":category_archive}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

generated URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/%2Fcategory_name/
```

%2F seems to be my extra character.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks for mentioning the question.

Comment: To solve the issue simply remove `/` from the beggining of `url(r'^/(?P<posts_category>\w+)/$', ... , ...)`